# General Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

have had some problem solving the following question: (I've done part 1.):

We have two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ and it says that $A=I-AB$.

1. Prove that $A$ is regular and $AB=BA$. (done this one is pretty easy)
2. Prove that if $B$ is symmetrical, so is $A$.
3. Prove that $B^3=0$ if and only if $A=I-B+B^2$.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: See also: [Two matrix proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1551298) and [Let $A,B$ be squared matrices. Given $A=I-AB$, Prove: $B^3=0$ if and only if $A=I-B+B^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3481593).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 2, factor $A$ and obtain $A(I+B) = I$. Check the transpose and notice the symmetric parts

For part 3, the necessity direction is shown by
$$
\begin{align}
AB &= I-A\\
AB^2 &= B-AB = B-I+A\\
AB^3 &= B^2 - B + AB = B^2 - B + I - A
\end{align}
$$
if $B^3=0$ then, $B^2 - B + I - A = 0$.

For sufficiency, 
$$\begin{align}
A &= I-B+B^2\\
I - AB &= I - B + B^2\\
-AB &= -B + B^2\\
-AB^2 &= -B^2 + B^3\\
(I-A)B^2 &= B^3\\
AB^3 &= B^3
\end{align}
$$
from this, we see that $(I-A)B^3=0$