# Two matrix proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

linear algebra problem I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around:

Given two square matrices $A,B$ with dimensions $n\times n$ and that $A=I-AB$ :

I've already proved with relative ease that $A$ is invertible and that $AB=BA$

Now I'm being asked to prove two more arguments:

1. Prove that if $B$ is symmetric then $A$ is symmetric as well
2. Prove that $B^3=0$ if and only if $A=I-B+B^2$

For the first argument I think one of the properties of symmetric matrices - the product of two symmetric matrices is also symmetric iff the two matrices commute - is helpful here. As for the second argument I really don't know where to start. Can someone shed some light on this please? Thanks!

Comment: Can you write B in terms of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=I-AB$ implies that $A(I+B)=I$, thus $A$ is the inverse of $I+B$. If $B$ is symmetric, $B^t=B$, thus $(A(I+B))^t=I^t=(I^t+B^t)A^t=(I+B)A^t=I$. We deduce that $A^t$ is also the inverse of $I+B$ thus $A^t=A$. Since the inverse of a matrix is unique.

, $(I+B)(I-B+B^2)=I+B^3$ thus $B^3=0$ iff $I-B+B^2$ is the inverse of $I+B$, this is equivalent to saying that $B^3=0$ iff $I-B+B^2=A$ since the inverse of a matrix is unique if it exists done.

Comment: Thanks! Wow this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$
A=I-AB
$$

next, plug $A=I-AB$ into the right hand side of this equation:
$$
A=I-AB=I-\overbrace{(I-AB)}^{\equiv A}B
$$
and simplify:
$$
A=I-B+AB^2
$$

next, repeat the same trick: replace $A=I-AB$ into the right hand side of this equation:
$$
A=I-B+AB^2=I-B+\overbrace{(I-AB)}^{\equiv A}B^2
$$
and simplify:
$$
A=I-B+B^2-AB^3
$$

This means that
$$
AB^3=I-B+B^2-A
$$

Thus, $B^3=0$ iff the r.h.s$=0$ (remember that $A$ is invertible, as you already know)

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard for me to follow your logic when the equation is written in a single line - is there any way you could break it down into separate lines, please?

Comment: @OrBairey-Sehayek I believe now it should be more clear.