# Let $A,B$ be squared matrices. Given $A=I-AB$, Prove: $B^3=0$ if and only if $A=I-B+B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ be squared matrices. 
>   Given $A=I-AB$,
>
> **Prove: $B^3=0  \iff A=I-B+B^2$**

The question has 3 sections:

> 1. Given $A=I-AB$, Prove that $A$ is invertible and that $BA=AB$.
> 2. Prove that if $B$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A$ is symmetric
> 3. Prove: $A=I-B+B^2$ if and only if $B^3=0$.

I proved the first two sections, and did the first direction of the third section, Thus we suppose that $A=I-B+B^2$, and I proved that $B^3=0$ as follows:

Suppose $A=I-B+B^2$, then $A=I-AB=I-B+B^2$
$$-AB=-B+B^2$$
$$\text{ we'll substitute $A$ by $I-B+B^2$}$$
$$-(I-B+B^2)B= -B+B^2$$
$$-B+B^2-B^3 =-B+B^2 \Longrightarrow B^3 =0$$
As wished.

Now let $B^3=0$. Prove: $A=I-B+B^2$. 
$$AB = I-A$$
We'll multiply by $B$ on the left side:
$$AB^2 = B-AB$$
$$AB^2+AB=B$$
$$AB(B+I)=B$$

and from this point I'm stuck.

Comment: These older question contain the same problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88304/general-matrix-question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551298/two-matrix-proofs
They can be found both [from Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24A%3DI-B%2BB%5E2%24&p=1) and [from SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7BA=I-B%2BB%5E2%7D$). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second case, just do iteration of the defintion of $A$.

$A=I-AB=I-(I-AB)B=I-B+AB^2=I-B+(I-AB)B^2$

$A=I-B+B^2-AB^3$

But $B^3=O$, then you have your definition of $A$